# How can I override the default region in aws provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a terraform configuration file like below. When I deploy `terraform apply` I got the error: `A default (non-aliased) provider configuration for "aws" was already given at │ versions.tf:37,1-15. If multiple configurations are required, set the "alias" argument for │ alternative configurations.`

I think it could be caused by some modules already defined the aws provider configuration. I know I can set an alias for the one I added at the bottom of below configuration. But how I can override the default one used by module?

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 3.20.0"
    }

    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "3.0.0"
    }

    local = {
      source  = "hashicorp/local"
      version = "2.0.0"
    }

    null = {
      source  = "hashicorp/null"
      version = "3.0.0"
    }

    template = {
      source  = "hashicorp/template"
      version = "2.2.0"
    }

    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.0.1"
    }
  }

  required_version = "~> 0.14"
}

variable "region" {
  default     = "us-east-2"
  description = "AWS region"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

locals {
  cluster_name = "education-eks-${random_string.suffix.result}"
}

resource "random_string" "suffix" {
  length  = 8
  special = false
}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "2.66.0"

  name                 = "elk-vpc"
  cidr                 = "10.0.0.0/16"
  azs                  = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
  private_subnets      = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets       = ["10.0.4.0/24", "10.0.5.0/24", "10.0.6.0/24"]
  enable_nat_gateway   = true
  single_nat_gateway   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
  }

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                      = "1"
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"             = "1"
  }
}


provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
}
```

Comment: Could you share your full Terraform code, ideally as a [mcve] please?

Comment: I have updated the  question to add vpc configuration which is full code I have

Comment: Overwrite what? You create alias if you want to have second provider with different settings, including region.

Comment: I don't want to use alias. What I mean is that if I put the `provider aws`, it will give us the error which means there is an existing `aws provider` inside the submodule. How can I overwrite the existing provider from outside?